# Accessing Outlook email info into excel worksheet (VBA): body, HTMLbody, RTFbody is <> empty

Tags: excel, email, vba

Thank in advance for the help... my Googleness has failed me today.

I have found quite a few sources on accessing email info with excel VBA, and for the most part I can get them to work.  But for some reason the most critical portion, the body of the email, is blank.

```
Dim myOlApp As Object, myNameSpace As Object
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myfolders = myNameSpace.Folders
n = 1
Do Until myfolders.Item(n) = "xxxxx"
    n = n + 1
Loop
Set myfolder = myfolders.Item(n)
Set myfolder2 = myfolder.Folders("Inbox")
c = 12
n = 36
For Each Item In myfolder2.Items
    itsj = Item.Subject
    itrt = Item.ReceivedTime
    itbo = Item.Body
    Cells(n, c) = itrt
    Cells(n, c + 1) = itsj
    Cells(n, c + 2) = itbo
    n = n + 1
 Next Item
```

Everything seems to work, except Item.Body.  I get a

Run-time error "287':
Application-defined or object-defined error

Looking at .body, or for that matter: .HTMLBody or .RTFBody, in the Locals view they are all showing a value of <>.  I've tried quite a few different emails from different people and always the same result.  I have also drilled down in the Locals folder for all the other objects to reference the email directly and same result.  I am using 2010 Outlook and Excel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no issues with mine, except it wasn't actually putting anything in the cell.
So, I modified it just a touch and put in the Application.ActiveSheet:

```
Dim myOlApp As Object, myNameSpace As Object
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myfolders = myNameSpace.Folders
n = 1
Do Until myfolders.Item(n) = "xxxxx"
    n = n + 1
Loop
Set myfolder = myfolders.Item(n)
Set myfolder2 = myfolder.Folders("Inbox")
c = 1
n = 1
For Each Item In myfolder2.Items
    itsj = Item.Subject
    itrt = Item.ReceivedTime
    itbo = Item.Body
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, c) = itrt
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, c + 1) = itsj
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, c + 2) = itbo
    n = n + 1
 Next Item
```

I'm on Office 2010.